# Batch convert BMP to both TIFF and JPEG, then have the converted images moved into respective folders

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I'm trying to modernise a film scanning workflow and need some guidance on how to automate my tasks more efficiently.

So let me first describe the situation and workflow that I need.

The film scanner produces a folder named after the Job Number (eg 2021_1234) with the actual film scans (.bmp) alongside cache/metadata files that are of no use at all (shown here as .xx and .zz). A sample directory is as follows:

```
~/2021_1234/
    01.xx
    02.xx
    03.xx
    01.zz
    02.zz
    03.zz
    01.bmp
    02.bmp
    03.bmp
```

I need the final result to follow this structure:

```
~/2021_1234/
    /2021_1234-TIFF/
        01.tiff
        02.tiff
        03.tiff
    /2021_1234-JPEG/
        01.jpg
        02.jpg
        03.jpg
```

Essentially the useless metadata files need to be deleted, and the .bmp files need to be converted to both .tiff and .jpeg files in their own subfolders with the Job Number as well.

Ideally I would like to also include LZW compression for the .tiff conversion if possible.

Currently I'm using a combination of manual copy/paste/delete, alongside 2 Automator Applications, 1 each for .jpeg and .tiff conversion. I'm only using a basic **Get Specified Finder Items** along with **Change Type of Images**.

It works, but it's not perfect as lots of manual steps still need to be done. Especially when I have to repeat all the steps for multiple jobs.

The ideal solution would allow me to simply drag 1 or multiple Job folders into an Automator Application and have it do all the image conversion, subfolder creation, and deletion of unnecessary files without any intervention on my end.

However, I can't seem to find a way to get the other steps done within Automator, and I get quite confused when I look at sample bash scripts that use sips. Many of the solutions I've seen online only solve one part of the problem that I'm facing (eg, just the image conversion, or just the folder creation), and I'm having trouble understanding the scripting language properly to combine them all together.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *example* **shell script** *code*, shown below, can be used as an **Automator** *workflow* created as either an *Application* or *Service/Quick Action*, using a **Run Shell Script** *action* with setting **Pass input: [as arguments]** and replacing the default *code* with it, as shown in the images further below.

For each *folder* dropped on the **Automator** *workflow* created as an *Application*, the *example* **shell script** *code* does the following:

- Changes *directory* into the dropped *folder*.
- Deletes the **.xx** and **.zz** *files* within.
- Makes the **Job Number-JPEG** and **Job Number-TIFF** *folders*, 
   e.g., **2021_1234-JPEG** and **2021_1234-TIFF**.
- Creates a **.jpg** type *file* and **.tiff** type *file* of each **.bmp** type *file* into their respective *folders*.

```bash
for dir in "$@"; do

    [ -d "${dir}" ] || continue
    [ -w "${dir}" ] || continue
    cd "${dir}" || exit
    rm *.xx *.zz
    dn="${dir##*/}"
    mkdir -p "${dn}-JPEG" "${dn}-TIFF"

    for file in *.bmp; do
        sips --setProperty format jpeg "${file}" -o "${dn}-JPEG/"
        sips --setProperty format tiff --setProperty formatOptions lzw "${file}" -o "${dn}-TIFF/"
    done

done
```

---

To use the *example* **shell script** *code* as an **Automator** *workflow* created as a *Service/Quick Action*, set **Workflow receives current [folders] in [Finder]**, as shown in the second image below.

Then in **Finder**, select the target *folder(s)* and *right-click* selecting the *Service/Quick Action* from the **Services** *context menu*.

---

**Understanding the *shell script***:

- `for dir in "$@"; do` -- For each folder dropped or selected, do the following:
- `[ -d "${dir}" ] || continue` -- Makes sure the **Finder** *item* dropped or selected is a *directory*, or continue with the next *item*.
- `[ -w "${dir}" ] || continue` -- Makes sure the **Finder** *item* dropped or selected is *writable*, or continue with the next *item*.
- `cd "${dir}" || exit` -- Changes *directory* to the dropped or selected *folder*, or exits the *shell script* to avoid erroneous processing of remaining *code*.
- `rm *.xx *.zz` -- Deletes all **.xx** and  **.zz** *files* within the `"${dir}"` *directory*.
- `dn="${dir##*/}"` -- Uses **shell parameter expansion** to get the *directory name* portion of the *fully qualified pathname* of the *folder* dropped or selected. Not actually necessary and could have just used `"${dir##*/}"` through the rest of the *code*, however, I believe it makes the remaining *code* easier to read.
- `mkdir -p "${dn}-JPEG" "${dn}-TIFF"` -- Makes the **Job Number-JPEG** and **Job Number-TIFF** *directories*,
  e.g., **2021_1234-JPEG** and **2021_1234-TIFF**.
- `for file in *.bmp; do` -- For each **.bmp** type *file* do the following:
- `sips --setProperty format jpeg "${file}" -o "${dn}-JPEG/"` -- Create a **.jpg** type *file* of each **.bmp** type *file* into the **Job Number-JPEG**, e.g., **2021_1234-JPEG** *directory*.
- `sips --setProperty format tiff --setProperty formatOptions lzw "${file}" -o "${dn}-TIFF/"` -- Create a **.tiff** type *file* of each **.bmp** type *file*, with the requested **LZW** compression, into the **Job Number-TIFF**, e.g., **2021_1234-TIFF** *directory*.

---

[image: Automator workflow as an Application]

[image: Automator workflow as a Service/Quick Action]

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me a lot.

Comment: @joelfong, I've modified the _shell script_ slightly and added an **Understanding the _shell script_:** section to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! That new section's really useful. I'm quite amazed how versatile and concise shell script can be. You've given me a great starting point to explore further.